# WCF Service - Custom Principal

Tags: wcf, principal

In the constructor of my WCF service class I am setting the current principal to be that of the principal passed in the header of the message:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<BBPrincipal>("bbPrincipal", "ns");
```

This seems to work fine, however when I come to reference the principal in a method, the Thread.CurrentPrincipal has reverted to a WindowsPrincipal.

Presumably the method is firing on a different thread. How can I ensure that the method is using the principal set in the constructor of the service?

Comment: You need to explain what is the goal you are trying to achieve. Do you want to run your service under a different account/impersonate? Of course the thread for processing incoming request will be different  from the one created the service.

Comment: Where are you executing this code: "setting the current principal to be that of the principal passed in the header of the message" - I'm very interested because I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just found the answer to my original question. In order to stop WCF overriding the principal with a blank one, set the following in the behavior configuration:

```
<serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None" />
```

Simple as that and no need to made sweeping changes to the existing code base.

See: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/369445/wcf-service-configured-for-transport-security-shouldnt-change-thread-currentprincipal

Comment: I did the same thank you! I tried setting the principal while validating the user credential (in a UserNamePasswordValidator) and can retrieve it in my services.
Anyway I was wondering if you experienced some misterious problem as everybody (and ms documentation) say: "set your principal in a custom authorization policy".
Tnx again in advance.

Answer (score 4):

WCF always sets principal in AuthorizationPolicy so it probably overwrites your changes. You should implement [custom authorization policy](http://leastprivilege.com/2007/08/08/custom-principals-and-wcf/) and set principal there.

Comment: +1 for principalPermissionMode="Custom".  Another useful example of this is in the DotNetOpenAuth sample code for the [OAuthResourceServer](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/tree/master/samples/OAuthResourceServer/Code)