# ASP .NET Custom Principal Overwritten

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iprincipal

I had some code that sets the HttpContext.Current.User with a custom IPrincipal in an Application.AuthenticateRequest handler.

This works fine and I've verified it's set correctly in the debugger...however, later down the pipeline when my WCF operation is called, the HttpContext.Current.User has been overwritten with a System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.

I feel like I've had and fixed this problem before but can't remember how or why it occurred.

Thanks.

Comment: Need a bit more information about your configuration. Is this SO question similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750016/wcf-service-custom-principal